# env file format weirdly

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I'm working on node project, I'm using .env file to hide some of data. The .env file worked normally, and after I added more informations it got some color letters for variable names and it won't detect my variables when i'm using:

`mongodb+srv://MONGODB_USERNAME:MONGODB_PASSWORD@cluster0.ekxmb.mongodb.net/MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

I'm having following code in my .env file:

```
MONGODB_PASSWORD = testpassword;
MONGODB_USERNAME = testuser;
MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME = testdbname;
```

It works when I manually type in app.js file code like this:

```
"mongodb+srv://testuser:testpassword@cluster0.ekxmb.mongodb.net/testdbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

After I added some additional variables code got formed weirdly with colors on variable names.

Note: It worked with code where I'm importing variables from .env file before, but after weird .env format it won't work.

Comment: `.env` files should not have spaces or semi-colon line terminators

Answer (score 1):

Putting a variable name in a string will just make it say that variable name. In addition, you don't have the environment variables loaded anywhere.

1. Install the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm package for processing the `.env` file. Then, add this to your code to load the config file:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
```

2. Create variables for each of your environment variables from `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME`. An easy way to do this is with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let {MONGODB_USERNAME, MONGODB_PASSWORD, MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME} = process.env;
```

3. Properly insert these variables into the string. You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this:

```js
`mongodb+srv://${MONGODB_USERNAME}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.ekxmb.mongodb.net/${MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
```

Comment: As I mention it worked, but it starts to break because .env file starts to form weirdly:
I'm using dot env and everything that you said, but the problem is:
`MONGODB_USERNAME=user1`
I had this in my file previously and it worked perfectly, but adding some additional it gets weird behaviour (When I save file):
`MONGODB_USERNAME = user1`
and MONGODB_USERNAME got this yellow colour instead of normal non-colour letter...
I'm sure then every value is correct because it works when I'm not using .env file...

Comment: I try to resolve the problem, and as I thought the problem was in auto-formatting, because when I save the .env file:
Instead of 
`MONGODB_USERNAME=user1`
I have
`MONGODB_USERNAME = user1;`
and when I console.log(MONGODB_USERNAME) the result is user1;, so this ; making a problem due to weird formatting in .env file